# Create multiple buttons on a canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to make a simple word game with the javascript canvas.

I have a url that looks something like:

`127.0.0.1:8000/join?scrambled_word=elolh&possible_words=hello&time=60`

I need to display each letter in scrambled_word, `e`,`l`,`o`,`l`,`h` as a button and be able to detect whenever one of them is clicked.

I tried getting the scrambled word as a char array and looping through and displaying it with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < game.scrambleArr.length; i++) {
     ctx.font = "bold 20px verdana, sans-serif ";
     ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
     //game.scrambleArr is just an array that contains the scrambled word from the url.
     ctx.fillText(game.scrambleArr[i], game.letterX, game.letterY);
     game.letterX += 40;
}
```

The issue with this is that this makes it difficult to detect whenever a letter is clicked.

How can I display these letters and make them clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the start position of the text, its height and the distance between letters, you can bind a `click` event to the `canvas` and then detect the clicked letter using `clientX` and `clientY` properties of the [mouse event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) and comparing them to positions of letters:

```js
let game = {
  scrambleArr: ['e', 'l', 'o', 'l', 'h'],
  letterX: 20,
  letterY: 40
}

let canvas = document.getElementById('c');
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let x = game.letterX;

for (let i = 0; i < game.scrambleArr.length; i++) {
     ctx.font = "bold 20px verdana, sans-serif ";
     ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
     ctx.fillText(game.scrambleArr[i], x, game.letterY);
     x += 40;
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = e.clientX - rect.left, y = e.clientY - rect.top;   
  if (y > game.letterY - 20 && y < game.letterY) {
    for (let i = 0; i < game.scrambleArr.length; i++) {
      let lx = game.letterX + i * 40;
      if (x > lx && x < lx + 40) {
        // we got the hit
        console.log(game.scrambleArr[i]);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  background: lightgrey;
}
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 5.3em !important; }
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=220 height=60></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is learning about topic "Hit Detection" because canvas is an "atomic" element of DOM.

It's not enough if only answer with a couple of lines.

Here is a tutorial for that:
https://blog.lavrton.com/hit-region-detection-for-html5-canvas-and-how-to-listen-to-click-events-on-canvas-shapes-815034d7e9f8

Comment: That would work great but the issue is that I don't have a circle object for any of the characters.  I have all of the characters stored in an array and loop through the array to display them.  In that tutorial he has objects that he can check the position of.

Comment: your buttons are rectangles in comparison with circles of the tut. Try to map what you saw from tut with your reality.